# Format specifier problem with numpy savetxt

Tags: numpy, formatting

I have four lists, one with strings and three with floats, which i want to write column-wise to a file. I read the lists from other files using numpy.loadtxt:

```
A = np.loadtxt(file_1, dtype=str, unpack=True, skiprows=1, usecols=(0))
x, y, z = np.loadtxt(file_2, unpack=True, skiprows=1, usecols=(1, 2, 3))
```

and would write the file using numpy.savetxt

```
np.savetxt(file_3, (A, x, y, z), fmt=('%s %15.8f %15.8f %15.8f'))
```

However, I get the following error:
ValueError: fmt has wrong number of % formats

`np.savetxt(file_3, (x, y, z), fmt='%15.8f')` and `np.savetxt('coord', atom, fmt='%s')` work fine. I have tried several variations, but cannot seem to get it right.
Thank you

```
input:
A = [a, b, c]
x = [1.1, 2.2, 3.3]
y = [4.4, 5.5, 6.6]
z = [7.7, 8.8, 9.9]

output:
a 1.1 4.4 7.7
b 2.2 5.5 8.8
c 3.3 6.6 9.8
```

Comment: Look at `np.array((A,x,y,z))`. Pay attention to shape and dtype. That's what `savetxt` is trying to format, one row at a time.

Comment: The shape is (4, 3) and dtype raises a TypeError: data type not understood